# How to fix error whenever I launch terminal?

Tags: python, bash, macos, terminal, virtualenvwrapper

A few months back, I was trying to download a virtualenvwrapper but I ended up setting up the wrong path

So whenever I launch my terminal the following problem appears:

```
Last login: Sat Apr 20 23:57:08 on ttys000
-bash: /usr/local/bin/python2: No such file or directory
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.
```

If Python could not import the module `virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader`,
check that `virtualenvwrapper` has been installed for
`VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python2` and that `PATH` is
set properly.

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/python2: No such file or directory
```

`virtualenvwrapper.sh`: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module `virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader`,
check that `virtualenvwrapper` has been installed for
`VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python2` and that PATH is
set properly.

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/python2: No such file or directory
```

`virtualenvwrapper.sh`: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module `virtualenvwrapper.hook_loade`r,
check that `virtualenvwrapper` has been installed for
`VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python2` and that `PATH` is
set properly.

Could anyone please recommend what terminal commands I have to give in order to eliminate this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the correct environment variables in your `~/.bashrc` file (or equivalent, if you use a different shell).

My `.bashrc` has these values:

```sh
# virtualenv(wrapper)
export WORKON_HOME=${HOME}/virtual-envs

export PROJECT_HOME=${HOME}/python_projects

source /usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```